# Calculating a % inside a case statement not working correctly

Tags: sql, sas, case, teradata, calculation

I am trying to work out the % of someones spend with a partner as a % of their overall spend across all partners. I am doing this within the below case statement..the code runs but when I test some examples that are flagged 90% they are under. I tried this using teradata sql, and have since solved the problem by doing it in multiple stages in SAS by calculating the %'s and then filtering them out. Just trying to understand why the below doesn't seem to be working correctly?

```
case when partner_spend > 0 and  partner_spend/total_spend >= 0.9 
    then '90% partner' 
    else 'other' 
end as spend_90
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the datatype of those columns? DECIMAL?

Answer (score 1):

Likely, the problem is integer division. If both values are integers or the-like, Teradata will produce an integer result, applying rounding rules: so basically if the results is `0.5` or greater, result will be `1`.

You can work around this by casting the values to decimal with sufficient precision, or by adding a (dummy) multiplier:

```
case when partner_spend > 0 and 1.00 * partner_spend/total_spend >= 0.9 
    then '90% partner' 
    else 'other' end 
as spend_90
```

Or:

```
case when partner_spend > 0 and cast(partner_spend as decimal(10, 2))/total_spend >= 0.9 
    then '90% partner' 
    else 'other' end 
as spend_90
```

Comment: If those columns are INT Standard SQL/Teradata will not apply rounding, but truncate, only DECIMALs are rounded :-)

Answer (score 0):

Unless `total_spend` can be negative, the first condition is not useful, so this can be simplified to:

```
(case when partner_spend * 1.0 / total_spend >= 0.9 
      then '90% partner' 
      else 'other' 
 end) as spend_90
```

Or, as I prefer:

```
(case when partner_spend >= total_spend * 0.9 
      then '90% partner' 
      else 'other' 
 end) as spend_90
```

I use a variety of databases and don't like to remember whether a particular database does integer division or not.  So, this avoids the division.

Comment: The first condition is useful to avoid a *division by zero* error.

Comment: Thanks all i understand now why it wasn't working and have applied the above to check and it works!